# What caused King Shark to turn on his teammates with the Green Lantern ring in "Suicide Squad: Kill the Justice League"?

Tags: dc, video-games, green-lantern, suicide-squad

In the video game *Suicide Squad: Kill the Justice League*, there is a scene where King Shark temporarily becomes a Green Lantern and manages to use his Green Lantern ring to create a huge shark-shaped construct that breaks through the enemy ship’s shield.

But then, King Shark seems to lose his mind and turns the shark construct against his own Suicide Squad teammates. They have to wrestle the ring off his finger to stop his rampage, and only then does he return to normal.

[image: screenshot of the described scene][image: screenshot of the described scene]

[image: screenshot of the described scene][image: screenshot of the described scene]

Video of the scene (relevant part starts at the 3:35:40 timestamp):

What was going on here? I don’t know much about Green Lantern (or King Shark) lore. How did the ring affect King Shark’s behavior? Why did he suddenly attack his allies with the ring’s power?

Comment: The general consensus I've seen is that the ring, not King Shark, was the one attacking, with it kind of hiacjking him. Partially supported by the ring's ability to kill (something canonically only possible with the approval of the Guardians), the ring may be a Brainiac simulacrum, which may mean that he was in control.

Answer (score -1):

Someone can't just randomly wear a Green Lantern ring and control it. The ring chooses the person who wears it. Since the ring didn't choose King Shark, it attacked King Shark.

Comment: Can you cite any evidence to support this?

Comment: "*Since the ring didn't choose King Shark, it attacked King Shark.*" Why was King Shark able to wield the ring, complete with a Green Lantern uniform, and use it to destroy the ship shield if the ring didn't choose him?

Comment: @galacticninja ring is commanded by will power. If person's will power strong enough, for a short amount of time wielder can use the ring with a limited power.

Comment: @LogicDictates you can look up to the dc database fandom wiki for the info. Also if you are familiar with the gl comics this is how rings work.

Comment: @hammer - I am familiar with DC comics and know that there's some truth to what you've said. However, since you posted this answer, the onus is on you to provide evidence from an official source to show that what you're saying is true. That's what I do when I post answers myself. And wiki/fandom sites are not considered a good reference source, as they're written by fans. The best way to evidence what you've said here would be with evidence directly from DC stories or DC writers.

Comment: I dont see why I should prove every word I write here. What I said is not a goverment secret that a person cant find. Anyone can look for golden age comics for the GL origin story and they will see this is how the rings works. Also fandom sites are one of the best sites to look for this kind of stuff since this is not some kind of science we are working with, info that is written there is %99 true.

Comment: @hammer Just so that I understand what you're saying correctly: King Shark wasn't chosen by the ring, but because his willpower was strong enough, he was able to wield the ring to destroy the ship shield. But since he wasn't chosen by the ring, the ring (not King Shark) eventually attacked King Shark and his teammates. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @galacticninja yeah but mine is just prediction. Normally he shouldnt be able to use the ring at all